# Changing child's coordinates when zooming uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Well, I have a scrollview in which I put the image principal MainIMG.
I also put 2 secondary images IMG1 and IMG2.

On the scrollview, i can zoom the principal Image (MainIMG), but not the secondary images (IMG1 and IMG2).
My problem is : i don't know how to make the secondary images retain their positions relative to the MainIMG when i zoom.

for example if IMG1 at the center of MainIMG when zoomScale = 1, it shall be as when zoomScale = 2.

thanks a lot for help

Comment: Did you try with setting anchors to center and using center positions for them ? Then in you zoom it should keep center in the same place.

Comment: thank you for replying Grzegorz, but IMG1 and IMG2 can be anywhere.
not necessarily in the center.

Comment: I'm talking about pivots (anchors). Instead of setting top, left X,Y you set center X,Y.

Comment: no, it does not solve the problem,
what i am looking for, is the formula to calculate the new IMG1's coordinates in order that IMG1 retains its position on MainIMG